# Pandas - '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: pandas

I would like to remove all rows that match two conditions:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['home'] == 'away')
           &(df['ranking'] > 12)].index)
```

But this is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: df ranking column type is string ?

Comment: it was scraped as text..so maybe, yes. how do I coerce the values to numerical before checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['ranking'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ranking'],errors='coerce')
```